# Java jar-file can not find .dll with jna.jar

Tags: java, dll, jar, jna

I am using a dll file in my java project and everything is working fine in IntelliJ IDE. I have end my project and now i have to export .jar file. And there is a problem. Of course I can not see any errors without console, but I am pretty sure all about is using this .dll file. I can not find any solution how to use .dll with .jar, I only fint that putting .dll inside .jar is not a good idea because we have to extract it in runtime. I tried keep .dll in the same folder as .jar but it does not work at all.

Can anyone show me the way, How to use .dll with .jar

I have used this dll
http://mediaarea.net/pl/MediaInfo/Download/Windows

and this as java files
https://code.google.com/p/subs4me/source/browse/trunk/Subs4me/src/net/sourceforge/filebot/mediainfo/?r=93

Answer (score 1):

There are several issues:

1.) Of course you can see the error on the console if you start your java application from console. Since it is a windows dll open 'cmd' and type java -jar yourApp.jar. Seeing the errors is important to track down your problem(s).

2.) When using/accessing a native dll from java it needs to be in the classpath. For that you wrap your dll inside a jar file (root of that jar) and make sure that jar file is in the classpath of your application. E.g. if you have your application.jar then add the dll.jar in the manifest file of the jar or specify it when running that jar using the -cp option

3.)s Depending which version of the dll file your are using (32 or 64bit) you need to use the right java version (32 or 64bit). The most compatible way would be to put both dll in the dll.jar and depending on what platform you are on, you choose the right dll...

Comment: It works to start from console, and I got exception like this "Exception in thread "Thread-2" java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: Unable to load library". But I do not know how to operate with this classpath when I am using .jar file.

Comment: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/deployment/jar/manifestindex.html There is a section about the classpath...